# Rails 3 does not render HTML as markup

Tags: html, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I submitted a form, to create single row in SQL database table, as a blog entry:

`<p>This is a paragraph.</p>`

And the result, when I query it out for display, via Rails's ActiveRecord, it rendered like this, :

`<p>This is a paragraph.</p>`

and here's the code, when I view source in browser:

`&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;`

How do I solve this? Or I just have to convert the **<** and **>** by Javascript?

**Thank you :)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening is that the string is being HTML-escaped.

You could use `html_safe` to not escape the string when it is rendered.
For example, `<%= post.paragraph.html_safe %>`.

But of course, that is **not recommended** in case you allowed the form to store (unrestricted) HTML in the first place, it could contain for example malicious JavaScript (eg for XSS). Needless to say that's extremely bad practice.

**Important Note** You should ensure that the HTML contains a *whitelist* of allowed HTML tags before using `html_safe` on any HTML. Additionally you might want to enforce the whitelist even when saving the form's contents (Note that enforcing whitelisting while saving *is not a substitute* for enforcing whitelisting when displaying the content!).

You might want to make a start by this [StackOverflow's own "rules"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user).